# How to indent for loop

Tags: indentation, loops

I would like to write the following pseudo code  :

```
data_points.foreach { point =>
    for(i <- point.size()) {
        do something....
    }
}
```

But when I try to use  \For \EndFor  I loose the indentation.

```
This is the code that i've tried:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}

  \Function{newCenterCalculation}{$data[vector]$}

    data\Call{.forEach}{point$\Rightarrow  $}
     \For{i $<$ point.size()} 
     \State {something} 
     \EndFor

  \EndFunction

\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

But it is produces the following:

[image]

What if the correct way to work with indentation within a for loop?

Comment: please show a complete small document that shows the problem and which of the algorithm/pseudocode  you are using.

Comment: Alex: you should, presumably, mark Paul's answer as being correct by giving it a green tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\State` to begin a new line for each simple statement (as you have done later for "something"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}

  \Function{newCenterCalculation}{$data[vector]$}

     \State {data\Call{.forEach}{point$\Rightarrow$}}

     \For{i $<$ point.size()} 
     \State {something} 
     \EndFor

  \EndFunction

\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! that solved issue

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
I posted this answer before the MWE appeared, so I didn't know that the [algpseudocode](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocode) package was being used. Still...

I would use the [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}
      data_points.foreach {
        point => for(i <- point.size()) {
            do something....
      }
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

See the package documentation if you want to add colour and/or special formatting.